# String validation help in Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with string validation. I need to test whether a parameter contains a string so a-z + 1-9 how do i do this?

```
public void setName(String one) {
    if(one.contains("[a-zA-Z]")) {
        this.name = one;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("unknown");
    }
}
```

this is the expected output i set it as `ok.setName("a")`
and the result is: 
unknown,
null

Comment: Please update with correct input and expected output. May be all you want is to check string is not null and not empty.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? - `if (one.matches("[a-zA-Z1-9]")`

Answer (score 2):

`contains()` doesn't take regular expressions.

You are looking for `matches()`

Example for your case (at least one alphanumeric except zero)

Partial Match

```
one.matches(".*[a-zA-Z1-9]+.*")
```

Or if you want exact matches then:

```
one.matches("[a-zA-Z1-9]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.contains()` - which searches if the String is a subset. You should be using `Regex` to test for pattern matching.

Try changing your `if` to the following:

```
if (one.matches("[a-zA-Z1-9]+")
```

Comment: when i set name(ok.setName("a");) for one charater " it works fine but when i add one more character "aa" it says "unknown",null

Comment: That's because this regex only matches a single character. You must add a `+` at the end to match a `String` made entirely from the characters it matches, as in `"[a-zA-Z1-9]+"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format to check if the string contains alphabets and numbers. String contains method checks if string contains particular substring/character, so you will need to use regex for that:

The regex in matches

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+
```

or

```
^[-\\w.]+
```

Both will work properly.

```
public void setName(String one) {
    if(one.matches("^[-\\w.]+")){
       System.out.println(one);
    }        
    else
       System.out.println("unknown");
}
```

Comment: when i set name(ok.setName("a");) for one charater " it works fine but when i add one more character "aa" it says "unknown",null

Comment: Now check with above code snippet it will work. done modifications in regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in ASCII alphanumeric characters, please use `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"` in `String.matches(regex)` which returns true if it is alphanumeric and false otherwise. Example:

```
public void setName(String one) {
        this.name = one.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") ? one : "UNKNOWN";
        System.out.println(String.format("name: %s", name));
}
```

Inorder to make it unicode compatible you can use `"^[\pL\pN]+$"` too in `String.matches(regex)`, where `\pL` stands for any letter
`\pN` stands for any number.

Answer (score 0):

To me readability is always the first thing to target, and terse does not always equal readable (regex is certanly terse)

I'd just do it manually, but regardless of which solution you choose please encapsulate it into a separate (readable) method call:

```
public boolean isStringAlphaNumeric(String test) {
    for(char c : test.toCharArray()) 
        if(!Character.isAlphabetic(c) || !Character.isNumeric(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```